# How do we know how many branches the inverse function of an elementary function has?

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, invariant-theory, branch-cuts

How do we know how many branches the inverse function of an elementary function has ?
For instance [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). How do we know how many branches it has at e.g. $z=-0.5$ , $z=0$ , $z=0.5$ or $z=2i$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your elementary function $f$ is entire and has an essential singularity at $\infty$ (as in the case you mention, with $f(z) = z e^z$). Then Picard's "great" theorem says that $f(z)$ takes on every complex value infinitely often, with at most one exception.  Thus for every $w$ with at most one exception, the inverse function will have infinitely many branches at $w$.  Determining whether that exception exists (and what it is) may require some work.  In this case it is easy: $f(z) = 0$ only for $z=0$ because the exponential function is never $0$, so the exception is $w=0$.

Comment: How do we go up the branch ? What is the invariant of $W(z)$ ?
$W(z) = W(f(z))$ ?
I seem to have trouble ' visualizing '.
@Robert Israel: Thanks for the answer. Could you help me with the questions above ?
I seem to have read a bad/confusing paper apparantly.

Comment: $W$ is supposed to be the (multivalued) inverse of $f$, so $f(W(z)) = z$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "go up the branch", but I suppose you may be asking how to connect the values at one point with those at another.  In brief, the answer is: analytic continuation.

Comment: Im aware of analytic continuation. I see now I asked my question incorrect. I did not type what i meant. Sorry.
Before i rephrase my question i will consider it again first and maybe i can find the answer myself.